# How to sum project values in column based on unique project ID?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So to describe my question, I created a simplified dataframe like this:

```
df_test <- data.frame(
  proj_manager = c('Emma','Emma','Emma','Emma','Emma','Alice','Alice'),
  proj_ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4), 
  stage = c('B','B','B','B','B','A','C'),
  value = c(15,15,20,20,20,70,5)
)
```

And I need to do some calculation on columns to prepare for viz. I created a new column that count the project based on project manager and project stage. I did:

```
input <- df_test %>%
  group_by(proj_manager, stage) %>%
  mutate(count_proj = length(unique(proj_ID)))
```

Now the data frame looks like this:

```
proj_manager proj_ID  stage value count_proj
    <fctr>   <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>      <int>
1         Emma       1      B    15          2
2         Emma       1      B    15          2
3         Emma       2      B    20          2
4         Emma       2      B    20          2
5         Emma       2      B    20          2
6        Alice       3      A    70          1
7        Alice       3      C     5          1
```

I want to create another column named'sum_value' that calculate the sum value of the project based on the same stage, but only different projects. For example, Emma has 'proj_ID 1' and 'proj_ID 2' in stage B, then the new column would sum the value of proj 1 and proj 2.  mutate(sum_value = sum(unique(value))) would do the trick for this simplified dataset, but when two different project ran into the same value, it would lead to an error.

Desired output would look like this:

```
proj_manager proj_ID  stage value count_proj sum_value
        <fctr>   <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>      <int>     <dbl>
1         Emma       1      B    15          2        35
2         Emma       1      B    15          2        35
3         Emma       2      B    20          2        35
4         Emma       2      B    20          2        35
5         Emma       2      B    20          2        35
6        Alice       3      A    70          1        70
7        Alice       3      C     5          1         5
```

Any good ideas?

Comment: Would you show the desired output. I think I got you wrong.

Comment: @Masoud Please check updated part :)

Comment: @Psidom already posted the answer. Cheers. Consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option use `group_by %>% do`; inside `do`, you can use `distinct` to get unique values per project and `sum` the result:

```
df_test %>% 
    group_by(proj_manager, stage) %>% 
    do({
        sum_value = sum(distinct(., proj_ID, value)$value);
        mutate(., sum_value = sum_value)
    })

#Source: local data frame [7 x 5]
#Groups: proj_manager, stage [3]

#  proj_manager proj_ID  stage value sum_value
#        <fctr>   <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1        Alice       3      A    70        70
#2        Alice       4      C     5         5
#3         Emma       1      B    15        35
#4         Emma       1      B    15        35
#5         Emma       2      B    20        35
#6         Emma       2      B    20        35
#7         Emma       2      B    20        35
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is to calculate the totals separately and then use `inner_join` to join to the given table

```
totals <- df_test %>%
  distinct(proj_ID, stage, value) %>%
  group_by(stage) %>%
  summarize(sum_value1 = sum(value))

input <- df_test %>%
  group_by(proj_manager, stage) %>%
  mutate(count_proj = length(unique(proj_ID)))  %>%
  inner_join(totals, by="stage")


input
#   proj_manager proj_ID  stage value count_proj sum_value1
# 1         Emma       1      B    15          2         35
# 2         Emma       1      B    15          2         35
# 3         Emma       2      B    20          2         35
# 4         Emma       2      B    20          2         35
# 5         Emma       2      B    20          2         35
# 6        Alice       3      A    70          1         70
# 7        Alice       4      C     5          1          5
```

Comment: Edited to match supplied output example.